# Is there any data type that you can set a lower and upper bound on the values it can take?

Tags: c++

I have to write a class that has a natural number taking values only in the (0, 15] range.

I can easily do some checking logic in the setter/constructor for that field - but is there any pre-defined data type which can achieve this behavior?

Comment: No. In particular, all predefined numeric types include the neutral element of ordinary addition, which your proposed type does not.

Comment: You could use a nibble, but I think any other reasonable approach would be better.

Comment: @user888379 No, a nibble would naturally represent the values [0 .. 16), not (0 .. 15].

Comment: @EOF I should have looked more closely at the endpoints of the range before making my unhelpful suggestion. And we're also ignoring the signed vs unsigned issue...

Comment: @user888379 What "signed vs unsigned issue"? There is no such issue here.

Comment: I was just positing that if we treated the high order bit of the nibble as a sign bit, then the range would be way out of whack. Just being silly, and I'm not actually helping the OP here, so I'll refrain from further silliness.